Feasbility of a underdetermined linear inequality system
Let $A \in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$ where $m<n$. Also let $x \in \mathbb R^n$. I assume that I do not know much about $A$ except all its elements are non-zero. Then, is there any lemma that says I can/cannot always determine a non-trivial solution of $Ax\geq 0$?
Thank you!

check Farkas Lemma
